# Issue with Nginx Url Rewrite /Redirect

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, redirect, rewrite, 301-redirect

For new site config  I tried NGINX rewriting for the  blog plan and keep the paths the same, just redirect from 'www.' to 'blog.'.

and plan for RSpace API and CME have been configured and the ALB.

```
www.qwerty.com/video/  www.qwerty.com/v/
```

**Blog**

```
www.qwerty.com/blog/category/educator-blog/
blog.qwerty.com/educator/
www.qwerty.com/blog/category/researcher-blog/
blog.qwerty.com/researcher/
www.qwerty.com/blog/category/librarian-blog/
blog.qwerty.com/librarian/
```

**RSpace API**

```
www.qwerty.com/api/external/
review.qwerty.com/api/external/
```

**CME**

```
www.qwerty.com/etc/cme_confirm.php
review.qwerty.com/etc/cme_confirm.php
```

**So I did try this for For the nginx**

```
# Redirect

server {

    listen      80;

    access_log  off;

    error_log   off;

    server_name www.qwerty.com/blog/category/educator-blog/;

    return 301 $scheme://blog.qwerty.com/educator/$request_uri;

}

# Redirect

server {

    listen      80;

    access_log  off;

    error_log   off;

   server_name www.qwerty.com/blog/category/researcher-blog/;

    return 301 $scheme://blog.qwerty.com/researcher/$request_uri;

}
    
  # Redirect
    
    server {
    
        listen      80;
    
        access_log  off;
    
        error_log   off;
    
         server_name www.qwerty.com/blog/category/librarian-blog/;
    
        return 301 $scheme://blog.qwerty.com/librarian/$request_uri;
    
    }
```

but its unable to fulfil our request  it seems to just spin, an URL (https://new-dev2.qwerty.com/video/49). Does the order of the rules matter?

I've implemented a temporary fix via the load balancer to have '/video/'

```
with 'www.qwerty.com' redirected to review.qwery.com/,
IF
Path is/video*
Host is www.qwerty.com
THEN
Redirect tohttps://review.qwerty.com:443/#{path}?#{query}
Status code:HTTP_302
```

which allows apache redirects to work. but i am looking for the parament fix for NGINX.

output

```
[root@ip-10-0-11-216 ~]# curl -I http://www.qwerty.com/blog/category/educator-blog/
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: awselb/2.0
Date: Mon, 10 Oct 2022 08:19:16 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 134
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://www.qwerty.com:443/blog/category/educator-blog/
```

What is the issue here , any help would be apricated.

Comment: Those are not valid `server_name` directives. See [server names](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) and [how Nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html).

Comment: Could you please describe it a little bit?

Comment: `server_name` contains the hostname part of URL, it must not include any other components of the URL.

Comment: I have tried this , but same fixed output : server {
    listen       80;
    listen       [::]:80;
    server_name www.test.com;
   location /video {
        rewrite /video(.*)$ /v$1 redirect;
    }

}